# web push serviceworker undefined method error?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-push

Every time I try to start up my server I get this error...

```
undefined method `post' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

**application.rb**

```
post "/push" do
    Webpush.payload_send(
      endpoint: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/gcm/send/eah7hak....",
      message: "A message",
      p256dh: "BO/aG9nYXNkZmFkc2ZmZHNmYWRzZmFl...",
      auth: "aW1hcmthcmFpa3V6ZQ==",
      vapid: {
        subject: "mailto:sender@example.com",
        public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
        private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
      }
    )
end
```

Am I putting the code chunk in the wrong spot? I assume `app.rb` is the same thing as `application.rb`

[image]

Screenshot is from git tutorial: https://github.com/zaru/webpush.

I'm trying to implement browser notifications with VAPID and gems `webpush` & `serviceworker-rails`.

**application.js**

```
// Register the serviceWorker script at /serviceworker.js from our server if supported
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js')
  .then(function(reg) {
    console.log('Service worker change, registered the service worker');
  });
}
// Otherwise, no push notifications :(
else {
  console.error('Service worker is not supported in this browser');
}

// When serviceWorker is supported, installed, and activated,
// subscribe the pushManager property with the vapidPublicKey
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
  serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager
  .subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: window.vapidPublicKey
  });
});

$('.webpush-button').on('click', (e) => {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready
  .then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
    serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
    .then((subscription) => {
      $.post('/push', {
        subscription: subscription.toJSON(),
        message: 'You clicked a button!'
      });
    });
  });
});

// Let's check if the browser supports notifications
if (!("Notification" in window)) {
  console.error("This browser does not support desktop notification");
}

// Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
  console.log("Permission to receive notifications has been granted");
}

// Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
  Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
  // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
    if (permission === "granted") {
      console.log("Permission to receive notifications has been granted");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are putting the code in the wrong place, `app.rb` is not for a rails app. Try using that code in a rails controller.

Comment: It all depends on your rails design, if you want to be your root page, then create root route, otherwise any route will do it. The same goes with a method name (aka action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example to add it in a controller.

First, create controller with the name of the action (i'll use `push`, to follow your example):

```
$ rails g controller Test push
```

That will create a Test controller and will update your routes:

```
# app/controllers/test_controller.rb

class TestController < ApplicationController
  def push
  end
end

# config/routes.rb

get 'test/push'
```

Next update controller with the code you want to add:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def push
    Webpush.payload_send(
      message: params[:message],
      endpoint: params[:subscription][:endpoint],
      p256dh: params[:subscription][:keys][:p256dh],
      auth: params[:subscription][:keys][:auth],
      vapid: {
        subject: "mailto:sender@example.com",
        public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
        private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
      }
    )
  end
end
```

And update your routes to use `post` instead of `get`:

```
post 'test/push'
```

With that you will have a POST *yoursite/test/push* endpoint available (just as the example with `app.rb`).

Comment: Yes, you are not sending any parameters to your action, so `params` hash is empty, thus, when trying to get `params[:subscription][:endpoint]`, you get  a `NoMethodError` because `params[:subscription]` is `nil` and `nil` does not respond to `[]` method (i.e. `[:endpoint]`). Instead of `link_to` use `form_for` or a simple html form with the parameters you need.

Comment: I tried `form_for` and `<%= link_to 'send', push_path, {message: 'YEAAA!', endpoint: 'value2', p256dh: 'value1', auth: 'value2', subscription: 'value1', keys: 'value2', method: :post} %>` but I still get the error. The values should be coming from the gems not me anyway so I am a bit confused on how to proceed. I asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572177/subscription-params-nil-for-web-push-serviceworker ... if you got the time to continue the conversation :) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi guys, any idea why  Webpush.payload_send(....) returns wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1; required keywords: p256dh, auth) using Ruby 3+